# How to handle error at update.php "The "views_bulk_edit:node" plugin does not exist"?

Tags: 8, upgrading

I'm updating drupal but cannot install the following update:

These updates are mentioned...

```
system module
Change plugin IDs of actions.
Clear caches due to schema changes in core.entity.schema.yml.
views module
Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage to entity_link.
Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters.
Fix cache max age for table displays.
Include views data table provider in views dependencies.
```

And then the error at running updata.php is:

```
system-module
change_action_plugins bijwerken
Mislukt: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "views_bulk_edit:node" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (regel 52 van C:\www\inzicht5\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

Any idea how to proceed with this?

Comment: Yes, install Views Bulk Edit again, so that you have the plugin https://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_bulk_edit/tree/src/Plugin/Action/BulkEdit.php